# Required element did not contain a wsu:id?

Tags: security, soap, jboss, web-services, soapui

I am new to soapUI 3.5. I tried some wsdl that acquire security against web service deployed on jboss 4.2.1

while running test on soapUI . It gives me

```
     <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <env:Header/>
     <env:Body>
     <env:Fault>
     <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPFaultException: Required element did not contain a wsu:id.</faultstring>
     </env:Fault>
     </env:Body>
      </env:Envelope>
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I found the solution over in the [JBoss Forum](http://community.jboss.org/message/541676#541676)

JBoss WS clients generate a wsu:Id attribute in the  element, which SoapUI will not insert automatically. Here is what my default SoapUI request looks like (view/edit using the XML tab):

```
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:getCutOffTime/>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

You can use SoapUI if you include a 'dummy' wsu:Id in the Body of your request.  Be sure to include the namespace:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="element-1-1272320911598-1522000" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <ser:getCutOffTime/>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

This solved the problem for me.  I was using JBoss 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a security exception.  I believe your WSDL is malformed or otherwise incompatible with the soapUI testing tool.  Its likely that other testing tools or client libraries will also throw exceptions.  Was this WSDL auto-generated? It should have been...

Answer (score 0):

The server that you ran against didn't like your request.  Probably because SoapUI built the sample using ? as placeholders, or perhaps "lorem ipsum" values.  Replace those with valid data, and it should go through.

If you have an app that can already talk to this server, you can usually copy/paste those requests into SoapUI.

Also, if you aren't able to capture those sample requests, run Fiddler on a PC, and it'll act as a proxy, and then it'll give you an easy way to capture sample payloads.  SoapUI can do it too, but Fiddler makes it really easy (auto-configures your WinInet to use itself as a proxy).